# Node Mongo Query Nest Object/Model _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the models:

```
var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  year: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
  },
 brand: {
    type: String,
    required: true
 },
model: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

});
```

and

```
var productSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  // Pictures must start with "http://"
  pictures: [{ type: String, match: /^http:\/\//i }],
  price: {
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    // Only 2 supported currencies for now
    currency: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['CAD','USD'],
      required: true,

    }
  },
  category: Category.schema,
  cars: [Car.schema],
  internal: {
    approximatePriceCAD: Number
  }
});
```

I'm trying to query the nested car _id, but it is not returning me any documents. Querying other car parameters such as model or brand will give me results but not _id.

For example,

```
app.get('/product/vehicle/:id', function(req, res) {
    Product.find({'cars._id' : req.params.id}, function(error, docs) {
      return res.json({products: docs});
    });
});
```

will return empty docs.

```
app.get('/product/vehicle/:brand', function(req, res) {
    Product.find({'cars.brand' : req.params.brand}, function(error, docs) {
      return res.json({products: docs});
    });
});
```

will return me the proper documents. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

The problem with the tests were that the product mock objects were created before the db insertion of cars. Therefore the _id was different when the products were created and stored in respect to the cars. There is nothing wrong with how it is queried.